# Pass multiple queries in GET request to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

```
// route.js

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const userHandler = require('../handler/user');

router.get('',userHandler.getUser);

module.exports = route
```

-

```
// Handler.js

const userController = require('../../core/controller/user');

// get user

getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log(req)
    try {
        let user = await userController.getUser(req.params.id, req.query.employeeStatus, req.query.department)
        req.data = user
        next()
    }
    catch (e) {
        req.status = 400;
        next(e)
    }
}

module.exports = {getUser}
```

-

```
// controller.js

exports.getUser = async (userId,employeeStatus,department) => {

    let userRecords = await userModel.getUser(userId,employeeStatus,department);
    userRecords = userRecords.map(it => {
        return {
            id: it._id,
            firstName: it.firstName,
            lastName: it.lastName,
            pic: it.pic,
            gender: it.gender,
            dob: it.dob,
            maritalStatus: it.maritalStatus,
            nationality: it.nationality,
            streetAddress: it.streetAddress,
            city: it.city,
            state: it.state,
            postalCode: it.postalCode,
            country: it.country,
            phone: it.phone,
            email: it.email,
            jobTitle: it.jobTitle,
            department: it.department,
            dateOfJoining: it.dateOfJoining,
            employeeStatus: it.employeeStatus,
            kra: it.kra,
            assignedSupervisor: it.assignedSupervisor,
            assignedSubordinate: it.assignedSubordinate,
            workExperience: it.workExperience,
            skills: it.skills,
            password: it.password
        }
    })
    return userRecords;
}
```

-

```
// query.js

exports.getUser = async(userId, employeeStatus, department) => {

    var whereClause = '';
    if (department) {
       var whereClause ={ "department":department}
       console.log(whereClause)
       console.log( Object.keys(whereClause).length)
    } 
    if(userId) return await model.find({"_id":userId}).exec();
    if (employeeStatus){
        console.log('debewbfewhfui')
        if ( Object.keys(whereClause).length) {
            console.log(whereClause)
            whereClause +=  ','
            console.log( whereClause.toSource())
            console.log(whereClause.hasOwnProperty("employeeStatus"))

            whereClause += {"employeeStatus":employeeStatus}
        }
        console.log(whereClause)
        //whereClause = {"employeeStatus":employeeStatus}
        console.log('e',  Object.keys(whereClause).length)
    // }])
        // console.log(department)
        // return await model.find({  $and: [ { $or: [{"employeeStatus": employeeStatus }] },{"department": department} ]  }).exec();
        // return await model.find({"employeeStatus":employeeStatus}).find({"department":department}).exec();
    }
    // if(department) {
    //     console.log('55')
    //     return await model.find({"department":department}).exec();
    // };
    // if (Object.keys(whereClause).length) {
    //     console.log(whereClause)
    //     whereClause = whereClause + ','
    // }
    var query = await model.find({$and : [whereClause] }).exec();
    console.log('fssd',JSON.stringify(whereClause))
    return query
}
```

I want if we pass any data department or employeestatus in query it will return data as required and if we dont pass any query then it will search all users. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conditionally compose the query filters depending on the parameters passed into the function, this should work:

```
query.js

exports.getUser = async (userId, employeeStatus, department) => {
  let queryFilters = { userId, employeeStatus, department };
  // The JSON stringify and parsing below would help remove undefined filter values
  // i.e if userId is not provided, while employeeStatus and department are given 
  // the queryFilters object would only contain employeeStatus and department.
  queryFilters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryFilters))
  return model.find(queryFilters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Is there any other way to use it with userId. If we pass userId and filters it will give result accordingly

Comment: "... Is there any other way to use it with userId..." -  Not sure I get this, the `getUser` function in the answer seems to be doing that already. I might be missing something, please help clarify.

Comment: its working fine when we are passing in query but if we pass userid in parmas and employeeStatus or department in query it does not works as queryFilters only contain employeeStatus and department. So   I am looking if it can work if we use api like ="localhost:port/user/userid?departmentName=.. It should work